# Is there an equivalent of require().default in TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm trying to build a small [Todo.txt](http://todotxt.org/) app for Android, using Ionic with Angular and Capacitor.

To handle the Todo.txt file, I am using a [todotxt-parse package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/todotxt-parse). So far, I have this on my page.ts file, and it's working:

```
declare var require: any; // <- This isn't nice :(
const TodoTxt = require('todotxt-parse').default;
const todo = new TodoTxt('Review pull request +TodoTxtTouch @github`');
console.log(todo.parse()); // <- Outputs an object with task metadata
```

However, I understand that that `declare var require: any;` is not a good practice.

Importing the module like this: `import { TodoTxt } from 'todotxt-parse';` causes an error `TS2305: Module /node_modules/todotxt-parse/lib/index"' has no exported member 'TodoTxt'`

On the other hand, changing the module's index.ts file from `export default class TodoTxt { ... }` to `export class TodoTxt { ... }` causes a `TypeError: todotxt_parse__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.TodoTxt is not a constructor`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import TodoTxt from 'todotxt-parse'
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html